# Could there be multiple asset pools In a DAMM liquidity pool?

Tags: oracles, exchanges, defi, decentralized-exchange

In a DAMM (dynamic automated market making) DEX (decentralized exchange) the ration between two assets, e.g. DAI/ETH does not have to be 50/50 anymore, like it used to be in a AMM, (automated market making). Because of dynamic price change by an oracle. So the ratio could be 90/10 as well, or anything.

Also, one could just provide liquidity to ETH for instance, and would still get LP tokens and fees.

Could there be liquidity pools of multiple assets? Sucha as DAI/ETH/LINK, where the ratio dynamically change based on providers and price changes.

And if yes, could there be a pool, where not just 3, but 100s of cryptos would be present?

Comment: Yes, there could.

Comment: NP, feel free close the question now, as it is pretty pointless as a question here.

Comment: If it's possible, is there projects like this? and why is there a single huge pool of liquidity at any project? or would it even makes sense from a profitability and efficiency point of view?